# Failing to properly print multidimensional array column?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, counter

I recently have been having trouble with this simple problem, at the end of the code there are two blocks of text dedicated to finding the highest/lowest grade from what the user inputted.

That was simple enough and it works well, but I also need to print the a row corresponding to the lowest/highest graded student.

Essentially I'm working with the marks[5][4] array, the first array being the students, the second array being the exams.

If the lowest graded student was the student on array [2][] then I would I want to print out [2][i] using a for loop.

For the second array it works fine, the problem is I'm having problem on how to link the lowest graded student to the first array link.

I tried to use the count1 and count loops but they return a mess. I have been at this for a few hours and need a nudge in the right direction.
Thank you very much.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{


    char grade[5];

    double avg[5];
    string name[5];

    int marks[5][4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        cout << "\n enter student" << i + 1 << "name :";
        cin >> name[i];
        cout << "\n enter four subject marks:";
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            cin >> marks[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            sum = sum + marks[i][j];
        }
        avg[i] = sum / 4;
        if (avg[i] > 90.0 && avg[i] <= 100.0) {
            grade[i] = 'A';
        }
        else if (avg[i] > 80.0 && avg[i] <= 90.0) {
            grade[i] = 'B';
        }
        else if (avg[i] > 70.0 && avg[i] <= 80.0) {
            grade[i] = 'C';
        }
        else if (avg[i] > 60.0 && avg[i] <= 70.0) {
            grade[i] = 'D';
        }
        else if (avg[i] <= 60.0) {
            grade[i] = 'F';
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "\nName :" << name[i];

        cout << "\tAverage : " << avg[i];

        cout << "\tGrade : " << grade[i];

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        int sum2 = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            sum2 = sum2 + marks[j][i];
        }
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "The average of each exam " << i+1 << " is " << "%" << sum2 / 5;
    }


    //LOWEST
    int count1;
    int lowest;
    lowest = avg[0];
        for (count1 = 1; count1 < 5; count1++)
        {
            if (avg[count1] < lowest)
                lowest = avg[count1];
        }
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "The lowest  average grade is is: " << lowest << ".\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            cout << marks[count1][i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    //Ends lowest.

    //HIGHEST
    int count;
    int highest;
    highest = avg[0];
    for (count = 1; count < 5; count++)
    {
        if (avg[count] > highest)
            highest = avg[count];
    }

    cout << "\n";
    cout << "The highest  average grade is is: " << highest << ".\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << marks[count][i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    //Ends highest.


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: `lowest` is the lowest average your code found. You just need one more variable, `lowest_n`, its index. And you happen to always set it every time you set `lowest` to a value. Mission accomplished!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you need to link the name with the lowest avg student

I recommend that instead of initializing `lowest` and `highest` with the average, initialize it with the index of the lowest and highest average. You can then compare the averages in the for loop like this

```
if (avg[lowest] >= avg[count1])
    
    lowest = count1;
```

or you can follow Sam's solution, create another variable to store the index of the current lowest and highest avg